# Remove textnode with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to remove a textnode from within a div but leave all the other elements in place. The character I wish to remove is a forward slash?

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
    <span>
        <a data-hovercard-type="user" data-hovercard-url="/hovercards?user_id=6715615" data-octo-click="hovercard-link-click" data-octo-dimensions="link_type:self"
        href="/davislf2">davislf2</a>
        /
        <a href="/davislf2/24322cb99c1a7a82fb64fe1f5816aef6">
            <strong class="css-truncate-target">css_common.css</strong>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6Lj74zt/)

This is the desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us anything that you actually _tried_?

Comment: Also, this seems to be pretty much a duplicate of your own question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538567/remove-textnode-from-github-gist-lists-using-css-or-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var childNodes = document.getElementById('text').childNodes;

childNodes.forEach(function(entry) 
{
    if(entry.textContent.trim() =='/')
    {
      entry.textContent =" ";
       //entry.remove(); //for remove 
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-block" >
  <span id="text">
   <a data-hovercard-type="user" data-hovercard-url="/hovercards?user_id=6715615" data-octo-click="hovercard-link-click" data-octo-dimensions="link_type:self"
   href="/davislf2">davislf2</a>
   /
   <a href="/davislf2/24322cb99c1a7a82fb64fe1f5816aef6">
    <strong class="css-truncate-target">css_common.css</strong>
   </a>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
var removeNode = $('span').children();
$('span').html('').html(removeNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

In that particular snippet you can do:

`document.getElementsByClassName('d-inline-block')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[2].remove();`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('d-inline-block')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[2].remove();
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-block">
  <span>
   <a data-hovercard-type="user" data-hovercard-url="/hovercards?user_id=6715615" data-octo-click="hovercard-link-click" data-octo-dimensions="link_type:self"
   href="/davislf2">davislf2</a>
   /
   <a href="/davislf2/24322cb99c1a7a82fb64fe1f5816aef6">
    <strong class="css-truncate-target">css_common.css</strong>
   </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: -1 for testing https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384203/i-can-add-1-to-a-comment-through-an-edit-but-not-during-comment-creation